# Failed to package using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, publishing

I am using ArcGIS Pro.

I am trying to share my project package. When I go to the package project tool, I type in my summary and tags, and then I analyze it. I get no errors from the analysis. When I hit package; however, I get a "failed to package" error without any further explanation. I am trying to save the package to a file on my C:drive and what I believe to be the parent file to my gdb within the project.

Any reason I may be having the issue?

[image: windows explorer folder]

[image: package project tool]

Comment: I am not sure, but you can select the option: Share outside of organization or Include History items

Comment: Did you view the log? If so what did it have to say? Can you create a new text file in the folder to ensure you have write access - this method quicker than resolving permissions. I wouldn't check Include Toolboxes unless there's a tool you want to distribute at the same time.

Comment: You need to tell us what the view log has in it.

Comment: My log shows that I have a Consolidating Toolbox error (Error 001659) - but when I use the "Analyze Tools for Pro" geoprocessing tool, my output file says that there were no issues found. I put the toolbox in question as my Input and saved the output file to my C: drive.

Comment: I figured it out - the toolbox was saved as ".atbx" instead of ".tbx" - not sure what the difference is or why that made a difference - but nonetheless, it worked. If anyone would like to explain the difference, I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks!